instances on curves non uniform "skewed" scaling
I am trying to find a formula (the green value button) to scale the instances and their Y rotation for getting the correct instance deformed transformation as in the image below, where you see in the detail it does not work well (they are instances). I can achieve this effect with realizing them and use the curve deforming, but just performance wise - is this possible with the instances? (the scene is made from a scratch and simplified as much I was able to do)

before the slope scaling:


all nodes:

instance manual value formula:

spiral:





I am trying to reformulate your expectation: you want to shear in Z direction the rectangular shape in such a way that the "left/right" edges remain vertical while the "top/bottom" edges are aligned with the curve tangent. The shear is achieved by combining a rotation and a scale. Is it right ?

Yes, exactly and the Z shape height stays the same as well, thanks

And you want that without realizing instances?

I know how to do this with realizing, this is just an idea how to partialy simulate deformation but still stay in good performance with thousands of instances. I cannot get this from my mind, but still cannot find any rule or trick...

looks promising https://imgur.com/a/43Ly6l7

It used to be the case you had to fiddle with rotations and scaling for skewing, which was basically matrix decomposition and recombination, just using "Geometry Transform" or equivalent nodes, but Blender 4.2 added matrices which makes it easier.
First, a standard setup - align cuboids on a spiral resampled to the $x = 0.4$ dimension, as this is the one aligned to tangent:

Obviously there are issues here, it is not ensured the spiral is divisible by 0.4 meters, and what happens when the climbing angle changes? A book can be written about that, but this question is about skewing, so I'll deal with just that:

The logic is simple:

Flatten the tangent you align to, so there's no need to unskew horizontally.
Shrink the instance to still fit, as flattened segments will be shorter than resampling target. Could be solved instead by non-even resampling of the curve but again, this is not the heart of the problem (and this one was solved before).
Similarly to above point, calculate how much you need to skew.
The heart of the problem: create a default 4x4 matrix (default inputs; all hidden inputs in my setups have default values), and in order to move $z$ (3rd) axis based on $x$ (1st) coordinate, modify the 3rd row of the 1st column.
Multiply the matrix by the one calculated by "Instance on Points".




Many thanks Markus, that is really great, will take me longer to understand with the matrices, I was quite close to the solution as well (my last comment above) when you mentioned it- in reality I am using curve sample node and the accumulate field to distribute the instances in a bit more precise way, this setup was just faster for me to prepare the file. It works really well https://imgur.com/a/lNvQ8Qq

Hi Markus, spent some time with this setup, still cannot get how to involve random scale and rotation of the instances but stlil keep the same slope alignment (even the instance is rotated 180 degrees - is this possible? Tried separating and combining transforms with inversions - but still not there.

@filanek maybe ask a new question with a sketch of desired results, as I find it unclear: for a 180 rotation it seems you just need to skew the other way? For scaled you need to scale the skew the other way? Or do you want to skew to fit,  and then just rotate, for some kind of disassembly effect?

hope this make it more clear: https://imgur.com/a/9M8jaYZ

scale: https://imgur.com/a/efq0Ozl

I am still basic in geonodes, if you know more elegant way, involving all axes show me please! https://imgur.com/a/R0HT19B

@filanek your gifs aren't very clear, I'd record with much bigger skew; still I can imagine what's the issue, but a more important question is what do you want to happen instead. And as I said, ask a new question as in write a new post.

just for the record https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/324545/rotation-of-the-instances-deformed-by-combine-matrix-node-on-spline-along-its-ta

(Using Blender 4.2.1)

This proposal is stricto sensu answering the formulated question by providing "a formula to scale the instances and their Y rotation for getting the correct instance deformed transformation", that happens to be a shear. It is adapted to Blender versions before 4.2. However since version 4.2, as judiciously answered by Markus von Broady, it is more straightforward to use Matrix nodes to implement shear instead of combining rotation and scale.

Approach
A shear in the (X,Z) plane in Z direction is computed as follows, dropping Y coordinate for simplicity:
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
X_1 & = & X_0 \\
Z_1 & = & Z_0 + K X_0
\end{array}\right. \label{eq_shear} \tag{1}$$
where $(X_0, Z_0)$ is the position before transformation, $(X_1, Z_1)$ is the position after transformation and $K$ is the shear coefficient.
In the context of the question, $K$ is defined by the angle $\gamma$ made by $\vec{t}$, the tangent to the curve, with the X direction, as $K=\tan{\gamma} = t_Z/t_X$ with $\vec{t}=(t_X,t_Z)$.
Using matrix formalism, Eq.(\ref{eq_shear}) is written:
$$ \left(\begin{array}{c}
X_1 \\
Z_1
\end{array}\right) = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
K & 1
\end{array}\right]
\left(\begin{array}{c}
X_0 \\
Z_0
\end{array}\right)  \label{eq_shear_matrix} \tag{2}$$
Such a matrix can be decomposed as the product of three matrices encoding two rotations around Y axis of angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and one nonuniform scale of coefficients $A$ and $B$, as:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
K & 1
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\beta} & -\sin{\beta} \\
\sin{\beta} & \cos{\beta}
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\
\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha}
\end{array}\right]
\label{eq_matrix_product} \tag{3}$$
Developing the products of the right hand side and writing the equality term by term yield a non-linear system of 4 equations, with 4 unknowns $\alpha, \beta, A$ and $B$ and 1 parameter $K$ (see the section "Mathematics" at the end for more details). Its solution is:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
A & = & \frac{1}{2} \left[ K + \sqrt{K^2+4}\right] \\
B & = & \frac{1}{A} \\
\tan{\alpha} & = & -B \\
\beta & = & \alpha - \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{array}\right. \label{eq_solution} \tag{4}
$$
GeometryNodes modifier

Matrix products of Eq.(\ref{eq_matrix_product}) are applied from right to left, i.e. first rotation of angle $\alpha$ (dark blue nodes), then scale of coefficients $A$ and $B$ (dark green nodes), eventually rotation of angle $\beta$ (dark red nodes).
NB: for the demonstration, the sequence of nodes connected to the Viewer node is computing the angle between adjacent edges. This value is displayed in the 3D Viewport activating the "Attribute Text" property in the "Viewport Overlays" options.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Mathematics
Eq.(\ref{eq_matrix_product}) is developed as:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
A \cos{\alpha} \cos{\beta} - B \sin{\alpha} \sin{\beta} & = & 1  \\
-A \sin{\alpha} \sin{\beta} + B \cos{\alpha} \cos{\beta} & = & 1  \\
-A \sin{\alpha} \cos{\beta} - B \cos{\alpha} \sin{\beta} & = & 0  \\
A \cos{\alpha} \sin{\beta} + B \sin{\alpha} \cos{\beta} & = & K
\end{array}\right. \label{eq_nonlinear_system} \tag{5}
$$
Linear combinations of lines of Eq.(\ref{eq_nonlinear_system}) lead to:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
\cos{\alpha} \cos{\beta} & = & (A-B)/(A^2-B^2)  \\
\sin{\alpha} \sin{\beta} & = & -(A-B)/(A^2-B^2)  \\
\cos{\alpha} \sin{\beta} & = & K A/(A^2-B^2)  \\
\sin{\alpha} \cos{\beta} & = & -K B/(A^2-B^2)
\end{array}\right. \label{eq_coscos_sinsin} \tag{6}
$$
Writing $\tan{\alpha}$ in two forms:
$$
\tan{\alpha} = \frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}} \frac{\cos{\beta}}{\cos{\beta}} = \frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}} \frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\beta}}
\label{eq_tan_alpha} \tag{7}
$$
leads to:
$$
(A-B)^2 = K^2 A B
\label{eq_K2AB} \tag{8}
$$
From the property:
$$
(\cos{\alpha} \cos{\beta})^2 +
(\cos{\alpha} \sin{\beta})^2 +
(\sin{\alpha} \cos{\beta})^2 +
(\sin{\alpha} \sin{\beta})^2 = 1
\label{eq_cos2sin2} \tag{9}
$$
it is derived:
$$
2(A-B)^2 + (KA)^2 + (KB)^2 = (A^2-B^2)^2
\label{eq_KX2KY2} \tag{10}
$$
Substituting Eq.(\ref{eq_K2AB}) in Eq.(\ref{eq_KX2KY2}) yields:
$$
K^2 = (A-B)^2
\label{eq_K2} \tag{11}
$$
From Eq.(\ref{eq_K2AB}) and Eq.(\ref{eq_K2}), it is derived:
$$
AB = 1
\label{eq_ABeq1} \tag{12}
$$
Assuming $A \gt B$, $K$ is written from Eq.(\ref{eq_K2}) as:
$$
K = A - B = A - \frac{1}{A}
\label{eq_KAmB} \tag{13}
$$
Consequently, $A$ is the positive root of the second order equation:
$$
A^2 - KA - 1 = 0
\label{eq_Aroot} \tag{14}
$$
i.e.
$$
A = \frac{1}{2} \left[ K + \sqrt{K^2+4}\right]
\label{eq_Adef} \tag{15}
$$
From Eq.(\ref{eq_ABeq1}), $B$ is defined as:
$$
B = \frac{1}{A}
\label{eq_Bdef} \tag{16}
$$
From Eq.(\ref{eq_tan_alpha}) and Eq.(\ref{eq_KAmB}), $\tan{\alpha}$ is defined as:
$$
\tan{\alpha} = -KB/(A-B) = -B
\label{eq_Alphadef} \tag{17}
$$
From Eq.(\ref{eq_coscos_sinsin}), it is derived:
$$
\tan{\beta} = -\frac{A}{B} \tan{\alpha} = A = \frac{1}{B} = -1 / \tan{\alpha}
\label{eq_AlphaBeta} \tag{18}
$$
Consequently,
$$
\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\cos{\beta}} = \frac{-\cos{\alpha}}{\sin{\alpha}}
\label{eq_tan_alpha_tan_beta} \tag{19}
$$
then
$$
\beta = \alpha - \frac{\pi}{2}
\label{eq_Betadef} \tag{20}
$$

Thanks, it works really well with the instances, my silly hack https://imgur.com/a/43Ly6l7, had some issues when the angle was 0...
