rotation of the instances deformed by combine matrix node on spline along its tangent
I have instances on curve, they are deformed by combined matrix node, I would like to achieve their rotation respects the curve tangent.
01-original file no rotation modified hires image:

original file and answer here original file
02-modification Z axis rotation works as I want hires image:


03-desired result-example from the different file - task is not the deformation but rotation and skewing only
and the pivot here is at the bottom, but pivot is not the case (here are realized instances with the curve deformation) hires image:

desired result look achieved by transformation of the cube before the instance on points:



Too bad the animations don't show bigger skew, because it would be easier to spot the logic. In particular, the desired y rotations seems wrong, as the objects seem to no longer rotate around their centers of masses, whereas I can see how the rotation you get on top animations is problematic because you get an overlap. This is one reason why I asked for a new question because I think the problem is under-specified. I see, however, how what you want is basically to rotate (and move in case of Y?) the rotation axes.

Also the desired result shows not just skewing but deformation - the long faces stretch and squeeze to keep  the continuity of the surface. Intended or a side-effect? There's probably more questions like that, it might be the biggest problem here to even understand what effect you're going for. In the end of the day you won't get a perfect fit on an arbitrary curve, because a point on a curve doesn't necessarily have symmetric neighbors.

desired is the rotation behaviour and skewing only, not the deformation (not possible with the instances)... if it is possible of course, there never be the same precision as in the realized version (all edges stay parallel)...

@Markus, see the last image, it is the exact result I am after...

...seems to me I got it working, multiplying the matrix the opposite way

If I am correct, the solution seems to be simple, it is just reversing the order of the matrix multiplier.

nodes:


