Shearing instances in geometry nodes
I am making a geo nodes for walls(and doors), but I am having trouble figuring out how to shear the instances. Here is my current node setup:

The delete geometry node just erases the ends. This looks like:

This makes is so I can use edges to express walls. However, if i raise a point to create a ramped wall, I get this:

It follows the rotation sometimes correctly, sometimes not. I believe this is due to my align rotation node, but what I really want is this:

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Hello, was figuring out the same not long time ago here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/324437/instances-on-curves-non-uniform-skewed-scaling/324569#324569

(Using Blender 4.2.2)
Approach

The overall transformation of each wall is done in two times. Firstly (see left side sub-figures above), using the explicit Rotation and Scale inputs of the Instance on Points node as well as its implicit Translation, walls are aligned and scaled in X and Y directions. The only transformation in Z direction is an offset such that a wall center is collocated with the associated edge mid-point. Secondly (see right side sub-figures above), a shear in Z direction is applied using a Set Instance Transform node.
Analysis
It is assumed that the building structure is defined by a mesh made of a set of edges in the XY plane, the Z direction being used for elevation. Let $\vec{t}=(t_X, t_Y, 0)^T$ be the unitary vector tangent to an edge in the XY plane, $L$ be the length of this edge projected on the XY plane, $h$ be the height of this edge projected in the Z direction, $C$ be this edge mid-point. Let $M$ be a point after the Instance on Points node and $M'$ be its transformed by a shear in Z direction proportional to its distance from $C$. $M'$ position is defined as:
$$
\vec{OM'} = \vec{OM} + \left( \vec{OM} - \vec{OC} \right) \cdot \vec{t} \times \frac{h}{L} \vec{e_Z}
$$
where $\vec{e_Z}$ is the unitary vector in Z direction. Consequently $X'=X$, $Y'=Y$ and:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
Z' & = & \vec{OM'} \cdot \vec{e_Z} \\
   & = & \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{e_Z} + \vec{OM} \cdot \vec{t} \times \frac{h}{L} - \vec{OC} \cdot \vec{t} \times \frac{h}{L} \\
   & = & Z + X t_X \frac{h}{L} + Y t_Y \frac{h}{L} + \vec{CO} \cdot \vec{t} \times \frac{h}{L}
\end{array}
$$
This relation is rewritten as the product of a line vector by a column vector as:
$$
Z' = \left( \frac{h}{L} t_X, \frac{h}{L} t_Y, 1, \frac{h}{L} \vec{t} \cdot \vec{CO} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} X \\ Y \\ Z \\ 1 \end{array} \right)
$$
It means that the 4x4 transformation matrix to apply is the identity matrix, except the third row associated to Z coordinate that is replaced by the above line vector.
GeometryNodes modifier

Math nodes:
1. The computation of different parameters is triggered by a single Capture Attribute node set in Edge domain.
2. The vector $\vec{P_2 P_1}$ aligned with an edge is computed by subtracting its end points position.
3. $\vec{t}$ and $L$ are computed after the projection of $\vec{P_2 P_1}$ on the XY plane.
4. $h$ is recovered by separating the Z component of $\vec{P_2 P_1}$.
5. The vector $\frac{h}{L} \vec{t}$ is captured under the name "Shear".
6. The position of $C$ is defined as the average of the position of $P_1$ and $P_2$. It is to notice the minus sign of the one-half factor because the vector $\vec{CO}$ is sought instead of $\vec{OC}$.
7. The displacement $\frac{h}{L} \vec{t} \cdot \vec{CO}$ is captured under the name "Offset".
Dark pink nodes:
A generic wall is made from a Cube mesh primitive such that local X direction is the thickness, local Y direction is the length and local Z direction is the height. Its length is set to 1 to be scaled afterwards to $L$. Its origin is at mid-thickness, mid-length and mid-height.
Dark red nodes:
8. The first transformation of the generic wall is implicitly performed by an Instance on Points node combining successively a scale, a rotation and a translation.
9. The scaling vector is set to $(1, L, 1)^T$.
10. The rotation is computed by an Align Rotation to Vector node such that the local Y direction of the generic wall is aligned with $\vec{t}$.
11. The translation is determined by a Mesh to Points node set in Edge domain, to spawn the scaled and rotated wall such that its origin is collocated with the edge mid-point.
Dark green nodes:
12. The shear matrix is assembled by editing the "Row 3" of a Combine Matrix node, which is providing by default the identity matrix. Only "Column 3" is unmodified.
13. Transformations are combined by multiplying matrices. In such a product, the right most transformation is applied first, while the left most transformation is applied last. Consequently, the shear matrix is connected first to the Multiply Matrices node, and the transformation already set by the Instance on Points node second.
14. Combined transformations are applied through a Set Instance Transform node.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.2+)

I have learned in the past couple of days that it had something to do with matricies, but it was a little too daunting for me. I did figure I needed to both rotate and shear, but the math was a hard to remember. Thanks for the great explanation!
